# How to keep a track of a website for a particular browser in a particular session

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, cookies, session-cookies

1.How to find that your website is being hit in the next tab of the same browser?
2. How to prevent the website from being opened in the second tab?

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do this. Browsers don't allow JS to access information about other open tabs for obvious security reasons.

Comment: might be impossible, unless you have somehow access to the raw client connections to the server, but even then HTTP connections are usually stateless and the connection is closed immediately.

Comment: Then how do bank website doesn't allow to copy the url in the next tab.

Comment: @Carcigenicate any server side solution?

Comment: @SunandanBose bank websites usually just use HTTPS, so most of the time you can't even use the "navigation buttons of your browser to go back or refresh the page, that will invalidate the session.

Comment: @VikramSingh I was trying to think of one. You would need to keep track of what clients you're currently connected to, and disallow more than 1 connection from a given client, based on something like their IP. That's riddled with problems though.

Comment: @Carcigenicate but when you identify a client via its IP only, that might lead to many problems because they can be behind a proxy or router so many users can share the same IP :)

Comment: @xander Which is why I said that it would be "riddled with problems". Only was I could think of though in my caffeine/sleepless state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the browser first calls your site, you create a session on server side which results in sending the session cookie to the browser. In your HTML you can embed a hidden form value. This hidden value must be included in every subsequent call. Best is to use always POST so that the hidden value isn't included in the URL.

If the user opens a second tab and want to open a URL of your site the hidden parameter is not included but the session cookie from the first tab is.

So at server side you know there is already a session but the hidden value is missing. So you can send a totally different response.

**Update**
Here a small example.

In web content folder there is a subfolder `protected`. All included JSP files should only be opened in one tab. Here there is only `MyJsp.jsp`.

In the root folder there are two JSPs: `error.jsp` which is displayed when someone is trying to open a protected JSP in a second tab. And `index.jsp` which redirects to `protected/MyJsp.jsp`.

And there is a servlet filter mapped to the `protected` folder. This filter will be called before executing the JSPs in this folder.

`protected/MyJsp.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello,
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty param.name}">
      <c:out value="${param.name}" />.
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      stranger.
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
  </p>
  <form method="post">
    <label>Please enter your name</label>
    <input id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
    <input id="marker" name="marker" type="hidden" 
        value="<c:out value="${sessionScope.marker}"/>"/>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This JSP is asking for a name. Form submit calls the same JSP via POST. The hidden field is filled with a value from the session.

`index.jsp`:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!--include the library-->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:redirect url="protected/MyJsp.jsp"/>
```

The servlet filter:

```
@WebFilter("/protected/*")
public class OneTabFilter implements Filter {

  private static final String MARKER_NAME = "marker";
  private static final String MARKER_VALUE = "4711*0815";

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request; 
    final HttpServletResponse rsp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
    if(session == null) {
      session = req.getSession(true);
      // Put the marker value into session so it is usable in JSP files.
      session.setAttribute(MARKER_NAME, MARKER_VALUE);
      // pass the request along the filter chain
      chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
      if(MARKER_VALUE.equals(req.getParameter(MARKER_NAME))) {
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
      } else {
        // Redirect to the error page.
        // The error page itself is not affected by this filter.
        rsp.sendRedirect(req.getServletContext().getContextPath() + "/error.jsp");
      }
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Try it yourself!

Comment: but won't that make our website slow if we start handling it from server for every single page it has to make two server calls once to make sure it is valid second to fetch the details.

Comment: It doesn't double the number of requests. There is a minimal performance loss to handle the additional hidden parameter for each call. For each request the server has to check for the presence of this parameter. That's it.

Comment: Maybe this check can be implemented by a Servlet filter.

Comment: @Sunandan Bose: I updated my answer with an example.